# Good MSbuild log formatter?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

we are building a very large Visual C++ 2010 solution (about 150 projects, full build takes about an hour) on a build server (Jenkins) with MSBuild. Unfortunately when a project fails, it is difficiult to find out which and why, because the console log is so long and errors are hard to find.

Is there a nice msbuild log parser or msbuild logger that nicely lists all failed projects and the error messages? The best we've found so far is the [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) but this is pretty much useless in many cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find the [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) very useful, though you need to provide your own parser file (in /jobs/vs_parsing_rules). I use the following, which works well for `msbuild`

```
error /[Ee]rror *:/
error /Error on line/
error /error [CM]/
error /fatal error/
error /unresolved external/
error /[aA]ccess is denied/
error /aborted/
warning /[Ww]arning *:/
warning /[Ww]arning C/
warning /WARNING/
warning /Couldn't/
warning /Can't/
warning /Cannot/
warning /ld.*unsupported/
error /[uU]ndefined symbols/
warning /[rR]eferenced from/
warning /[nN]ot found/
warning /exit status/
warning /no symbols/
error /ERROR[^A-Za-z]/
info /INFO/
start /BUILD/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another useful parsing rules that works for msbuild:

```
# Divide into sections based on project compile start
start /^------/

# Compiler Error
error /(?i)error [A-Z]+[0-9]+:/
error /MSBUILD : (?i)error :/
error /\(\d+(,\d+)?\): (?i)error [A-Za-z]*:/

# Compiler Warning
warning /(?i)warning [A-Z]+[0-9]+:/
```